# How to create an image from a string?

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to create an image file from a string, but so far I have not had any luck. Using ImageDraw I can print a string on an image file, but this is not what I intend to do. I want to generate just a simple image file from a set of characters.

Edit: Imagine a hypothetical case of creating an ASCII art text of a pic, but instead of creating an output of a text file, generate an image file. My code consists of multiple loops and using Matplotlib will affect my code's performance.

Answer (score 2):

you could try matplotlib:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.text(0,0,mystring)
plt.savefig("mysentence.png", dpi=100)
```

Comment: This is a good idea, but I think the overhead is a bit too much for my current task. I'm trying to generate images of different characters in a loop, and this might not be the best idea.

Comment: @FarhoodET Please improve your question to clarify properly what you are trying to do if that is the case. Currently it doesn't mention a loop...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`PIL.Image.frombytes` method](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.frombytes)

```
import PIL

my_string = b'\xf8\xff\xb0\xbc\xd8]\xba\xdf0\xbd\xdeE\xfb\xff\xd1\xf1\xff\xbf\xb4\xd9p\xad\xd9F\xae\xd7U\xf2\xff\xd6\xdf\xff\xdc\xde\xff\xd2m\xa8L\xe0\xff\xc5\xe0\xff\xe1F\x9a\\I\x9e]E\x9bTD\x9aSK\x9fa1\xadO,\xa7L3\xaeT/\xa9R.\xa8Q'
img = Image.frombytes("RGB", (5,5), my_string)
img.show()
```

Note, that the length of your string must equals the number of bytes used for a pixel multiplied by the width and height of the image.

In my case `my_string` holds an RGB image, that makes 3 bytes per pixel and the image is 5 pixels width and 5 pixel high.

Therefore `my_string` should have a length of 75 bytes (3 * 5 * 5)

Comment: I don't understand how does this relate to my question. I have copied your code and added an img.save(path) line but the resulting image has a filesize of 0. BTW, my problem is to generate image of characters, not translating a series of characters into an image.

Comment: I must have misunterstood your question then. However saving works fine for me